# jQuery - how to simplify the code

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var lnkAgreement = $('#lnk-agreement');
        if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
            lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
            lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
        }
        else {
            lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
            lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
        }
        $('#IsConsultant').click(function () {

            if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
                lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
                lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
            }
            else {
                lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
                lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
<a href="#" id="lnk-agreement"></a>
```

How to avoid from iterative blocks of the code?

Comment: If you have a recent jQuery version, use `.prop('checked')` instead of `.attr('checked')`

Comment: You can also chain the jQuery calls together: `lnkAgreement.attr(...).text(...)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster, is there a difference between  .prop('') and .attr('')?

Comment: The difference between .prop() and .attr() explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @nickf: While true, this clearly doesn't improve the readability in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function for it:

```
function Test(){
     if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
          lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
          lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
     }
     else {
          lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
          lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it all in a function.

```
function myFunction() {
    if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
        lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
        lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
    }
    else {
        lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
        lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
    }
}
```

Then call that function on document ready and on the click.

```
$('#IsConsultant').click(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myMethod(){
if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
            lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
            lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
        }
        else {
            lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
            lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
        }

}

myMethod();

$('#IsConsultant').click(function () {
 myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very quick refactoring gave me this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    // select the dom elements
    var lnkAgreement = $('#lnk-agreement');
    var isConsultant = $('#IsConsultant');


    setLnkAgreement(isConsultant.attr('checked'));

    isConsultant.click(function () {
        setLnkAgreement(isConsultant.attr('checked')
    });
});

function setLnkAgreement(isConsultant){
    if (isConsultant) {
        lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")');
        lnkAgreement.text('service provider agreement');
    }
    else {
        lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")');
        lnkAgreement.text('user agreement');
    }
}
```

You need to move your common functionality into a function of its own and then clal that with the required parameters.

Regards,

James

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function chooseAgreementLink() {
    if ($('#IsConsultant').attr('checked')) {
        setAgreementLink("ServiceProviderAgreement", "service provider agreement");
    }
    else {
        setAgreementLink("UserAgreement", "userprovider agreement");
    }
}
function setAgreementLink(controller, text) {
    var lnkAgreement = $('#lnk-agreement');
    lnkAgreement.attr('href', '@Url.Action(controller, "Home")');
    lnkAgreement.text(text);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setAgreementLink();
    $('#IsConsultant').click(function () {
        setAgreementLink();
    };
};
</script>
```

Comment: You **should** put the `$('#IsConsultant').click()` handler set inside your `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var lnkAgreement = $('#lnk-agreement'),
        isConsultant = $('#IsConsultant'),
        handler = function () {
            var isChecked = isConsultant.is(':checked');
            lnkAgreement
                .attr('href', isChecked ? 
                    '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")' : 
                    '@Url.Action("UserAgreement", "Home")'
                    )
                .text(isChecked ? 'service provider agreement' : 'user agreement')
                ;
        };

    isConsultant.on('click', handler);
    handler();

});
```

1. Chain your methods when you can,
2. Encapsulate in a function when you can,
3. Cache your variables when appropriate.

I'm thinking you can simplify your Razor as well by omitting `"Home"` from the `UrlHelper.Action` method if you're calling it from a view within the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
$(document)
.ready(function () {
var a = $("#lnk-agreement");
$("#IsConsultant")
    .attr("checked") ? (a.attr("href", '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")'), a.text("service provider agreement")) : (a.attr("href", '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")'), a.text("user agreement")), $("#IsConsultant")
    .click(function () {
    $("#IsConsultant")
        .attr("checked") ? (a.attr("href", '@Url.Action("ServiceProviderAgreement", "Home")'), a.text("service provider agreement")) : (a.attr("href", '@Url.Action("UserAgreement","Home")'), a.text("user agreement"))
})
})
```